# JQuery .each() Function assigning the same ID for children elements (not iterating?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to iterate through a list of children elements and pass their encrypted IDs via AJAX to my controller to update display order on drop using jQuery Sortable. jQuery is selecting the correct amount of child elements but it is assigning the same ID from the dragged and dropped item to both items in my array. I'm not sure what's going on.. I would really appreciate the help! Thanks

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       
        $(".reqconsentList").sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            update: function (event, ui) {

                var consentForms = [];

                $(this).children().each(function (index) {
                    consentForms.push({ 'id': $('#ConsentID').val(), 'position': index + 1 });
                 
                });
                
                var data = { 'sortedConsentForms': consentForms };
                //debugger;
                // POST to server using $.post or $.ajax
                $.ajax({
                    data: data,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateConsentDisplayOrder", "Check", new { Area = "Administration" })'
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code and data should not be presented as images.

Comment: Also note that id must be unique, means you can't have multiple elements with the same id

Comment: Each Encrypted field has the same DIV ID. #ConsentID is a field in the ConsentItemTemplate partial and is being populated with an encryptedID for each record as it iterates the partial with Model data. I have tried this using Class instead of ID as well with the same result.

Comment: You should try something like `'id': $(this).find('.ConsentID').val()`

Comment: That fixed it! That should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that `$('#ConsentID').val()` would return the value from the first element with that id. ID needs to be Unique.

Changing the jquery to `class` would be correct, but the code would still not know what "element" it should get the data from.

So we need to tell it search for the `.reqconsentList`, to look for child with the class `.ConsentID`

This is done this way: `$(this).find('.ConsentID').val()`